# EJB 3.1 JSP JPA MySQL How to get a foreign key

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have two classes and also two tables called *Car* and *Reservation*. The table *Reservation* has a `foreign key` of *Car* in a one-to-one relationship.

I can fill the jsp file with all the attributes of the `class Reservation`...but I don't know how to get the `foreign key` of Car...should I make a direct call through **jdbc** and a **sql statement** in the *servlet* or are there any other ways to get the `foreign key` of a special car?

For example:

In my Reservation class I have 4 attributes called `id`, `name`, `surname`, and a car `attribute`. Within the *Reservation servlet* I can set values for these `attributes` but I don't know how to get the car id from within the *Reservation servlet*.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple

create a mysql query for your car table.

```
Select id from car_table where car_attribute='car';  
while(rs.next){
x=rs.getString("id");
 }
```

car_attribute=column name that is common to both the tables.

car=column value that is common to both the tables.

Comment: Thank yo very much...will try this